# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml News-Please

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to install a Python package called `news-please`. This package is already on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/news-please) and on [Github](https://github.com/fhamborg/news-please).

When I do `pip install news-please` as shown on the Github page, it shows the following:

```
Collecting news-please
  Using cached news-please-1.1.48.tar.gz
Collecting Scrapy>=1.1.0 (from news-please)
  Using cached Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyMySQL>=0.7.9 (from news-please)
  Using cached PyMySQL-0.7.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hjson>=1.5.8 (from news-please)
  Using cached hjson-2.0.7.tar.gz
Collecting elasticsearch>=2.4 (from news-please)
  Using cached elasticsearch-5.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
beautifulsoup4>=4.3.2 in c:\users\[my name]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages 
(from news-please)
Collecting readability-lxml>=0.6.2 (from news-please)
  Using cached readability-lxml-0.6.2.tar.gz
Collecting langdetect>=1.0.7 (from news-please)
  Using cached langdetect-1.0.7.zip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-
dateutil>=2.4.0 in c:\users\[my name]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from 
news-please)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): plac>=0.9.6 in 
c:\users\[my name]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from news-please)
Collecting dotmap>=1.2.17 (from news-please)
  Using cached dotmap-1.2.17.tar.gz
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from news-please)
  Using cached PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz
Collecting warcio>=1.3.3 (from news-please)
  Using cached warcio-1.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ago>=0.0.9 (from news-please)
  Using cached ago-0.0.9.tar.gz
Collecting newspaper3k (from news-please)
  Using cached newspaper3k-0.2.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pywin32>=220 in 
c:\users\[my name]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from news-please)
Collecting lxml>=3.35 (from news-please)
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml>=3.35 (from 
 news-please) (from versions: 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 1.0b0, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 
 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1a0, 1.1b0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3b0, 1.3, 
 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 2.0a1, 2.0a2, 2.0a3, 2.0a4, 2.0a5, 
 2.0a6, 2.0b1, 2.0b2, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 
 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.1a1, 2.1b1, 2.1b2, 2.1b3, 2.1, 2.1.1, 
 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.2a1, 2.2b1, 2.2b2, 2.2b3, 2.2b4, 2.2, 2.2.1, 
 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.3b1, 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 
 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1b1, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 
 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.3.0b1, 3.3.0b2, 3.3.0b3, 
 3.3.0b4, 3.3.0b5, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4, 3.3.5, 3.3.6, 3.4.0, 
 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.5.0b1, 3.5.0, 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.2, 3.6.3, 
 3.6.4, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, 3.8.0)
No matching distribution found for lxml>=3.35 (from news-please)
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' 
command.
```

Now the problem is the part where it says it cannot find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml >=3.35.

I already have a version of lxml which is greater than 3.35. When I do `pip show lxml', it tells me that the version I currently have is 3.8.0.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you have already satisified [these dependencies](https://github.com/fhamborg/news-please/blob/master/requirements.txt):

```
pywin32 >=220 ; sys_platform == 'win32'
lxml >=3.35 ; sys_platform == 'win32'
Scrapy>=1.1.0
PyMySQL>=0.7.9
hjson>=1.5.8
elasticsearch>=2.4
beautifulsoup4>=4.3.2
readability-lxml>=0.6.2
newspaper3k>=0.1.7 ; python_version >= '3.0'
newspaper>=0.0.9.8 ; python_version == '2.7'
langdetect>=1.0.7
python-dateutil>=2.4.0
plac>=0.9.6
future>=0.16.0 ; python_version == '2.7'
PyDispatcher>=2.0.5
dotmap>=1.2.17
warcio>=1.3.3
ago>=0.0.9
```

then you could use

```
pip install --no-deps -U news-please
```

to have pip install news-please without the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Information on how to install news-please on Windows can be found in the documentation, e.g. https://github.com/fhamborg/news-please/wiki/user-guide#windows-systems

According to that, you'll need to install lxml and pywin32:

```
lxml:

Go to Christoph's Gohlke's Python page and download the compatible wheel for your system.
(32bit : "lxml-X.X.X-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"; 64bit: "lxml-X.X.X-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl")

Open the Windows console and navigate to your Python installation:

 C:\Users\USERNAME>cd  C:\Python35  
Install the wheel with the following command:

 C:\Python35> pip install lxml-X.X.X-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl  
pywin32:

Download the latest build of pywin32.
Make sure you select correct version (matches Python version, 32bit/64bit)

Execute the installer
```